# How to update socket.data for all sockets, from one socket

Tags: reactjs, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have multiple sockets running, each with socket.data.roomIndex.
Upon an event in the front end with a specific socket emitting an event, in that listener in the server, I want to call all sockets to update roomIndex. I'm not sure how, because io.emit, socket.emit, socket.broadcast.emit, io.broadcast.emit, io.socket.broadcast.emit doesn't work.

frontend:

```
  if (room.exists) {
    socket.emit("join_room");
  }
```

server:

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  ...
  socket.once("join_room", () => {
    ...
    // HERE //
    socket.emit("subtract", removedIndex);
    ...
  }
  
  ...

  // all other sockets should listen here
  socket.on("subtract", (removedIndex) => {
    if (socket.data.roomWaitingLobbyIndex > removedIndex) {
      socket.data.roomWaitingLobbyIndex -= 1;
    }
  });
  
  ...
}
```